# PHP Web Push Notification Error Message - [WebPush] gmp extension is not loaded but is required

Tags: php, push-notification, notifications, gmp, web-push

When I try to send a web push notification the following error is shown:

**[WebPush] gmp extension is not loaded but is required for sending push notifications with payload or for VAPID authentication. You can fix this in your php.ini.**

Interestingly, the notification works, but I don't understand why I still get the error message.
I tried what was suggested in other Stack Overflow posts related to the [PHP Web Push Notification library](https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php) but they did not work.

I prevented the error message from showing by commenting out the key value pair in the library that contains the error message which can be found in minishlink -> web-push -> src -> WebPush.php(line 73).

Notifications still send even though it's commented out.

It's not wise to do so as that may interfere with highlighting another issue(s) that may arise but I don't know what else to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to uncomment the GMP extension in php.ini?

Comment: @chenshuiluke Yes I did but it didn't work.

Comment: Hmm, it's possible that the module itself isn't installed on your server, which might be why it's still erroring out after you enabled it in your php.ini. What hosting provider do you use?

Comment: @chenshuiluke Interestingly, the error appears in the localhost/development environment but not the production environment. I deliberately did not comment out the key value pair in minishlink -> web-push -> src -> WebPush.php(line 73) on the live website (phoenixprime.io) which is hosted on Hostinger.com to see what would happen and no error was generated or shown.